# RxJava2, Android -> Whats wrong in this unittest

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, rx-java2

I do not know why this error is occurring. I need to test if database Interface is called in successful. I tried for a few hours without success.

**Class**

```
class VisitUseCase(private var webService: WebService, private var databaseInterface: SupervisorDatabaseInterface) : VisitUseCaseInterface {
    fun getVisitsFromApi(): Single<List<VisitsItem>> {
            Log.e("API", "API")
            return databaseInterface.getUserToken()
                    .flatMap { it -> webService.getVisits("Token ${it.token}", "future", "true") }
                    .map { it -> it.visits!! }
                    .doOnSuccess { it -> databaseInterface.insertListOfVisits(it) }
        }
```

databaseInterface.getUserToken("","","") -> return Single - UserToken -

webService.getVisits() -> return Single - RoutineVisit-

map -> ruturn List- Visits -

**Test**

```
class VisitUseCaseTest {
    private val immediateScheduler = object : Scheduler() {
        override fun createWorker(): Worker {
            return ExecutorScheduler.ExecutorWorker(Executor { it.run() })
        }
    }


var webService: WebService = Mockito.mock(WebService::class.java)

var databaseInterface: SupervisorDatabaseInterface = Mockito.mock(SupervisorDatabaseInterface::class.java)

var mVisitUseCase: VisitUseCase = VisitUseCase(webService, databaseInterface)


@Before
fun setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    RxJavaPlugins.setInitIoSchedulerHandler { immediateScheduler }
    RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { 
    immediateScheduler }
    RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler { immediateScheduler 
    }
}

@After
fun tearDown() {
    RxJavaPlugins.reset()
    RxAndroidPlugins.reset()
}


@Test
fun `success get from api`() {

    val listSingleVisit = Single.just(listOf<VisitsItem>())

    val userTokenSingle = Single.just(UserToken())

    val routineVisitsSingle = Single.just(RoutineVisits())

    `when`(webService.getVisits("", "", "")).thenReturn(routineVisitsSingle)
    `when`(databaseInterface.getUserToken()).thenReturn(userTokenSingle)

    mVisitUseCase.getVisitsFromApi().test().assertNoErrors()

    verify(databaseInterface, 
    times(1)).insertListOfVisits(listSingleVisit.blockingGet())
}
```

}

**Whats happining**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Error(s) present: [java.lang.NullPointerException: The single returned by the mapper is null] (latch = 0, values = 0, errors = 1, completions = 0)

    at io.reactivex.observers.BaseTestConsumer.fail(BaseTestConsumer.java:191)
    at io.reactivex.observers.BaseTestConsumer.assertNoErrors(BaseTestConsumer.java:276)
    at test.id.domain.visitUseCase.VisitUseCaseTest.success get from api(VisitUseCaseTest.kt:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: The single returned by the mapper is null
    at io.reactivex.internal.functions.ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(ObjectHelper.java:39)
    at 

io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFlatMap$SingleFlatMapCallback 
     .onSuccess(SingleFlatMap.java:76)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleJust.subscribeActual(SingleJust.java:30)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3096)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFlatMap.subscribeActual(SingleFlatMap.java:36)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3096)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleMap.subscribeActual(SingleMap.java:34)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3096)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleDoOnSuccess.subscribeActual(SingleDoOnSuccess.java:35)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3096)
    at io.reactivex.Single.test(Single.java:3534)
    ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mock setup is not what you want it to be:

```
`when`(webService.getVisits("", "", "")).thenReturn(routineVisitsSingle)
```

Will return `routineVisitsSingle` only if `webService.getVisits` is called with empty strings, but your code calls it like:

```
webService.getVisits("Token ${it.token}", "future", "true")
```

Your mock should be setup with something like this instead:

```
`when`(webService.getVisits("Token ", "future", "true")).thenReturn(routineVisitsSingle)
```

It's up to you (and your code's logic) to decide if you want to mock exactly for those values, or you want to use something like `any()` or other [Matchers](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.21.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html)